How to withdraw from Remix Ethereum IDE when after start narrative the Etherium was not transfered on ETH Balance?
Deployed contract on Remix Ethereum IDE, after starting narrative, following problem experienced ETH not reflected on balance.
0.5331354 ETH value transferred after taxation.
When checked on Ether scan, ETH balance is zero.
Appreciate any assistance for this.

0xe3b40d305088EC70dbB393Ed354fD51D8e8DaA5c

Hi, Remix IDE doesn't hold your funds. It looks like you deployed a contract and called a function that sent your eth to itself then to what looks like a scammers address: 0xf9f4ce209eabc701faea14063551742207063568. | Is it a scam arbitrage bot, or something similar? | If you don't own the wallet that received the eth there isn't a way for you to get it back. Certainly has nothing to do with Remix, who warn you not to copy and paste contracts you don't understand.

See here for most common answers to this question: I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?
